# How to apply regular expression on user input in vscode snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am using react hooks. I using a global context with reducer. Instead of writing each `case` of reducer function inside function. I want to separate in in the files. Example of my file is below

```
export type SetDrawingDataAction = {"set-drawing-data": Data};
export function setDrawingData(state : IGlobalState, data: number) : IGlobalState{

}
```

In the above file you can that I am using the name `SetDrawingData` at three places but with different formats.

Currently my snippet looks like below but its not making `setDrawingDataAction` capital.

```
"Generate Action file": {
  "prefix": "actd",
  "body": [
     "export type ${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/} = {\"\": Data}",
     "export function $1(state : IGlobalState, data: Data) : IGlobalState {",
     "  $2",
     "}"
  ],
  "description": "Generate action file witn data"
}
```

Kindly answer how can I change formats by using only single inputs. The first one is to capitalize the can second need is to change `camelCase` to `camel-case`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is `setDrawingData` try this snippet:

```
"Generate Action file": {
  "prefix": "actd",
  "body": [
     "export type ${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}Action = {\"${1/(.*)([A-Z][^[A-Z]*)([A-Z][^[A-Z]*)/$1-${2:/downcase}-${3:/downcase}/}\": Data}",
     "export function $1(state : IGlobalState, data: Data) : IGlobalState {",
     "  $2",
     "}"
  ],
  "description": "Generate action file witn data"
}
```

Here is the output of that snippet:

```
export type SetDrawingDataAction = {"set-drawing-data": Data}
export function setDrawingData(state : IGlobalState, data: Data) : IGlobalState {

}
```

[image: snippet demo]

Comment: Not working for me. Do you press any key after typing `setDrawingData`?

Comment: You have to press `tab` after `setDrawingData` to complete the transform.  `Like a Variable-Transform, a transformation of a placeholder allows changing the inserted text for the placeholder when moving to the next tab stop.`  from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholdertransform What that mean is that the transform happens when you go to the next or last stop.

Comment: I added a gif that shows the final `tab` that is necessary.  You can either type `setDrawingData` as I did in the gif or paste it in - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well no. maybe I am missing something obvious

Comment: Hmm, are you on v1.41 of vscode?  What doesn't work?  You can trigger the snippet?  Type your `setDrawingData`, hit `tab` - what do you get?